# Using a std::vector<> as an Objective-C property

Tags: properties, objective-c++

I have an Objective-C++ class that I wish to have a property which is a C++ `std::vector<std::string>`. I've declared it like this:

```
@interface WordModel : NSObject

@property std::vector<std::string>  words;

@end
```

When I attempt to add words to the `vector` nothing happens. For example, in the `-init` method, I'm doing this:

```
    std::string nextLine;
    while(wordsFile.good())
    {
        std::getline(wordsFile, nextLine);
        if (nextLine.length() > 0)
        {
            self.words.push_back(nextLine);
        }
    }
```

After calling `push_back()` the debugger reports the `self.words` `vector` as still being empty. Why? There are no error messages either during compilation or at runtime.

If I change the property into an ivar, everything works as expected. That is, if I make it into this:

```
@interface WordSetModel : NSObject
{
    std::vector<std::string>    words;
}
@end
```

I'm confused as to why there's such a difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An Objective-C property is simply a pair of getter and setter methods that you can access using a dot notation. For a property `@property std::vector<std::string> words;`, the getter and setter methods would be:

```
- (std::vector<std::string>)words;
- (void)setWords:(std::vector<std::string>)w;
```

(I am assuming that you didn't implement the getters and setters, so it auto-synthesized them. But even if you implemented them yourself, I believe it would still have to have the above type signatures.)

When you read from `self.words`, that is just syntactic sugar for a call to the getter: `[self words]`. Notice that the getter returns an `std::vector` *by value*. I think that that is your problem here. When you pass or return something by value, it is copied. So you are getting a temporary copy of the vector, pushing to it, and then discarding it. The vector in the underlying instance variable is unchanged. For a method to be able to give you something that can allow you to change the underlying vector, it would have to return to you a C++ "reference", something like `std::vector<std::string> &`. I am not sure whether you can do that with an Objective-C property (I haven't tried).

Comment: D'oh! Of  course, it's by value. It should have been obvious.  Thanks!

Comment: How did you make it pass by reference?